# how to add email id as hyperlink in trigger error message?

Tags: email, errormessages

How can I add an email id as a hyperlink in a error message in a trigger?

Comment: Where should this show up ? Standard pages or visualforce pages ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You shouldn't.**

Triggers are executing when your data is manipulated, from whatever context (UI or API). It would be a bad design to assume which interface is the source of your trigger execution and create user specific messages at that point.

That beeing said, that doesn't always applies to salesforce, as for standard pages you don't have the luxery of running custom controllers, and validation rules kinda skip the same principle.

**ALSO: mailto hyperlinks are not perceived as user friendly** by most users and often only work well with device installed email clients, and not with web email clients (I believe).

Comment: You are right Samuel.Emaito: is not working.Though it is coming as hyperlink,but onclick it is not going to the web mail page.is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 8):

Use [`addError(String, Boolean)`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError_2) with `false` to the second parameter so that it'll not escape `HTML` markups in your string message.

```
obj.addError('ERROR:<a href=\'your_link\'>More details</a>', false);
```

Found [this similar post](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hCnmAAE) on success community.

Comment: Thanks highfive.It id working.But onclick on the hyperlink it is not going to the email page.

Comment: The answer is just to explain how we can apply `HTML` formatting with the `addError` method. As @SamuelDeRycke has mentioned **mailto hyperlinks** are not going to be work well always without email clients

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer to the question tbh.

Comment: This solution works in Classic but the escape parameter is ignored in Lightning. Hopefully Salesforce either fixes this in Lightning or creates another method of passing a hyperlink back in an error.

Answer (score 1):

You  can use apex:pageMessage tag with escape="false" then  use try catch to catch the error from trigger and format the error putting html tags for email id. Now apex page message will display hyper link

Comment: It is a standard page.