# How to display hyperlink in error message from trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, adderror

i want to give link to the record in an error message which i am sending from trigger.

Message:

```
ERROR: An open opportunity <a href='https://bonial3-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/0065i000006VOl0AAG'>Dickenson Mobile Generators</a> already exist, please close it first before creating new.
```

code:

```
String url = URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+opportunityList[0].Id;
opp.addError('ERROR: An open opportunity <a href=\''+url+'\'>'+opportunityList[0].Name+'</a> already exist, please close it first before creating new.',false);
```

I have tried almost all the soln given on :

[how to add email id as hyperlink in trigger error message?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41368/how-to-add-email-id-as-hyperlink-in-trigger-error-message)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615794/hyperlink-in-trigger-error-message

[How to display a error message with hyperlink on standard detail page through trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/327420/how-to-display-a-error-message-with-hyperlink-on-standard-detail-page-through-tr/379731#379731)

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7ckfSAB

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8D8tSAF

update: found one thing this code is working in classic but not in lightning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation for the [SObject addError method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError_2) you can't escape html in Lightning. If this code has to run in a trigger then I guess you're out of luck.

> public Void addError(String errorMsg, Boolean escape)
>
> Escape, Type: Boolean
> Indicates whether any HTML markup in the custom
> error message should be escaped (true) or not (false). This parameter
> is ignored in both Lightning Experience and the Salesforce mobile app,
> and the HTML is always escaped. The escape parameter only applies in
> Salesforce Classic.

Comment: so there is no workaround to achieve this?

Comment: @AdityaSahu I'm afraid not